# Picking a value from another table in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes

I have two tables:

`'TableA'` has an auto incrementing `"id"`
`'TableB'` has a field that needs the `"id"` from `'TableA'`

How do I default on update when a user updates `'TableB'`? I need the maximum value from `'TableA'`.

In SQL terms this would be:

```sql
select max(id) from tableA
```

How can I translate the above into QGIS language with the layer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The expression you should use should be

```
aggregate( layer:='your_layer_id_for_A', 
aggregate:='max', 
expression:="your_id_column_for_A")
```

You will apply it in the layer form part from your layer B (and may use "Apply default value on update") e.g below screenshot

[image: Expression default value in form]